# Phpmyadmin showing same field as both a blob and Text field

Tags: text, phpmyadmin, blob

When I view a mysql table "structure" in phpmyadmin - two fields are shown as text.
Then, i view them using browse... and they show as blobs.

No other tables on my server are doing this.

Any else ever experienced this?

http://www.mybaby.net.au/text1.jpg